# JQuery Using Closest("element.class")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the closest tr that also matches a specific class name. The selector returns no matches.  What am I not understanding?

For example:

```
<table>
<tbody class="category" id="cat-1">
<tr class="category-head">
  <th>Category 1</th>
</tr>
  <tr class="category-item">
    <th>Item 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a description of category item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="c1_i1_input" id="c1_i1_input" class="category-item-input" /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr class="category-item">
    <th>Item 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is a description of category item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="c1_i2_input" id="c1_i2_input" class="category-item-input" /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".category-item-input").change(function () {
           //this works, returning the closest tr
            alert($(this).closest("tr").html());

            //this returns null?
            alert($(this).closest("tr.category-item").html());
        });

    });</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closest finds the closest ancestor element, not the nearest in the DOM.  In your case the `tr` containing the input does not have the class and so the selector fails.  You probably want to find the closest `tr`, then find the preceding previous sibling of that `tr` with the class.

```
$(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr.category-item:last');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and providing a quick solution!